# Using a CFF / Type1c / Type2 font in Java

Tags: java, pdf, fonts

I'm trying to use some of the fonts embedded in PDF files in a Java application. Apparently, Java is able to load Type1 and TrueType fonts. According to several websites the Type1c fonts in a PDF are basically a CFF or Type2 font. A new feature of Java 7 is to load CFF font but Font.createFont() by this doesn't work.

So where am I going wrong? Is a Type1c font really a CFF/OpenType font? Is there any conversion required?

Comment: Font.createFont with the data embedded in the PDF doesn't work, no matter which type parameter I use. Since the old Java PDF parser project from SUN is able to parse the font as Type1C, I assume I'm passing the correct bytes to the createFont method.

Comment: How doesn't it work? Does it throw an exception? Or does it seem to work but then there are no glyphs displayed? As Mark hinted at, fonts can be embedded in PDFs only as far as they are needed. Do you have any relevant code to look at? And a sample PDF which in combination with your code allows to reproduce the problem?

Comment: createFont with TYPE1_FONT results in "java.awt.FontFormatException: bad pfa font", for TRUETYPE_Font it's "java.awt.FontFormatException: Unsupported sfnt /tmp/+~JF4438581181045380297.tmp"

Answer (score 2):

Is the font subsetted? (in which case it will contain only some characters and not the whole font).

In general CFF fonts embedded in PDFs can need a lot of conversion work to make them generally usable - if you have been following the development of our PDF to HTML5 converter on our blog (http://blog.idrsolutions.com), you will have seen lots of posts about various issues with fonts.

[sfntly](https://github.com/googlefonts/sfntly) and [fontforge](https://fontforge.org/) are useful tools for font manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to find out exactly what battle you're trying to fight I'm afraid. Don't believe web sites about fonts, read the PDF specification:
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Specifically you're looking for chapter 9.6 - Simple Fonts and 9.7 - Composite fonts.

To summarize, the fonts in a PDF file can be a number of types:
- Type 0
- Type 1
- Type 3
- TrueType

Type 1 and TrueType are the simplest ones and you're very likely to encounter them in PDF files. Type 3 is a font type where you can use graphics to draw the characters. Not very common.

Type 0 is a more complex font type which was originally devised to allow you to use large character sets (think Japanese / Chinese), but it is now also routinely generated by many professional design and layout applications. There are two subtypes of this Type 0 font type:
- SubType 0, which is a Type 1 font massaged into a Type 0 jacket, and
- SubType 2, which is a TrueType font massages into a Type 0 jacket

In all cases there are significant differences between "real" fonts that live on your system and those same fonts embedded in a PDF file.

Start by having a look at the PDF file with the fonts you want to use. Use a tool such as pdfToolbox from callas (http://www.callassoftware.com/callas/doku.php/en:download) or Browser from Enfocus (http://www.enfocus.com/en/products/browser). Both of these tools allow you to investigate the low-level structure of a PDF file, including looking at the actual page description code and looking at the font dictionaries. pdfToolbox is particularly good at diving into the fonts in a PDF file, including looking at the actual shapes and the instructions used to draw those shapes.

Answer (score 0):

FontVerter is an open source java lib I wrote a little bit ago that can convert bare CFF* and Type0/composite fonts that come from PDFs into OTF/TTFs and WOFF1/2. It can also attempt to fix and normalize OTF/TTF fonts that don't work correctly in browsers, I found open type fonts embedded in PDFs often had various issues like missing tables which would prevent chrome from rendering them correctly.

[FontVerter github](https://github.com/m-abboud/FontVerter)

(*bare CFF = type1c I believe?, it's been a little and I'm forgetting which type is which)